# after email deleting attachment file, error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am doing an email form. Email has attachments and after attaching files email is sent. Next there is requirement to delete file from server. When I tried to get the file it gave me the subject error. I am even calling GC.Collect() before deleting the file but error is still there. My code for deleting file is:

```
 private void DeleteFiles(DataTable dt)
{
    GC.Collect();
    String[] sAttachments = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
    try
    {

        sAttachments = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (Int32 J = 0; J < dt.Rows.Count; J++)
        {
            sAttachments[J] = dt.Rows[J]["AttachmentExt"].ToString().Trim();
            string workDir = Server.MapPath(".") + @"\upload\";
            if (File.Exists(workDir + sAttachments[J]))
                File.Delete(workDir + sAttachments[J]);                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

For attaching file to email my code is:

```
 oMess.Subject = sSubject; 
        string workDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + @"\upload\";
        if (Attachments != null)
        {
            for (Int32 I = 0; I < Attachments.Length; I++)
            {
                oatt = new Attachment(workDir+ sAttachments[I]);
                oMess.Attachments.Add(oatt);
            }
        }
        oMess.IsBodyHtml = IsHtml;
        oMess.Body = sBody;
       SendMessageGmail(oMess);
```

Edit: My mail sending code is:

```
 private void SendMessageGmail(MailMessage message)        
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("myid", "mypassword");
        client.Credentials = loginInfo;
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Send(message);
    }
```

Plz guide and help. thanks

Comment: What type is oMess? If it's `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` you could try calling `Dispose()` before attempting to delete the files.

Comment: @rsbarro, should I call Dispose() after sending email ? or after oMess.Attachments.Add(oatt) ?

Comment: @user576510 Try after sending the email but before attempting to delete the files. Calling Dispose() on the MailMessage will Dispose the attachments as well.

Comment: @rsbarro, I did but still getting same error message.

Comment: @user576510 Can you post more of the code? AFAIK the Dispose should have worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After execute "SendMessageGmail", free the attachment of MailMessage.Attachments by iterating.

```
SendMessageGmail(oMess);
if(oMess.Attachments != null) {
  for(Int32 I = oMess.Attachments.Count - 1; I >= 0;I--) {
    oMess.Attachments[i].Dispose();
  }
  oMess.Attachments.Clear();
  oMess.Attachments.Dispose();
}
oMess.Dispose();
oMess = null;
```

Answer (score 19):

Use this one. It worked for me

```
client.Send(oMess);
oMess.Attachments.Dispose();
```

I tried this one but it didn`t work for me

```
client.Send(oMess);
oMess.Dispose();
```

Comment: the last one worked for me. I'm using it with `using`: `using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage ()) { /* setup and send mail */ }`

Answer (score 14):

You should try to do
`oatt.Dispose();`

Comment: should I call Dispose() after sending email ? or after oMess.Attachments.Add(oatt) ?

Comment: Try after `oMess.Attachments.Add(oatt);`

Answer (score 3):

```
oMess.Dispose()
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to fill the imagebox  this will solve the problem of deleting the file.

```
pictureBox1.Load(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(attachment, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

objEmail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, new FileInfo(attachment).Name));

file.Close();
ms.Close();
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
System.IO.File.Delete(attachment);
```

Comment: Above code is working fine but need to change one line  objEmail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), new FileInfo(attachment).Name));

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SendMessageGmail(MailMessage message)       
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("myid", "mypassword");
    client.Credentials = loginInfo;
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Send(message);
    oatt.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: oatt was not declared